# SQL Server Reporting Services Issue

Tags: reporting-services, https, ssrs-2014

We are using SQL Server 2014 Reporting Services to produce reports. Recently, we have had to switch our links to https. Since that time, we are unable to access the reports from outside the local server. When accessed, we only get in return the message "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

We have tried configuring the web service url for SSRS to use the SSL certificate, but that does not seem to resolve the issue. Is there a setting somewhere else that needs changed?

Comment: Did you follow all the steps outlined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345223(v=sql.120).aspx